# Finding multiple groups in one string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Figure the following string, it's a list of html a separated by commas. How to get a list of {href,title} that are between 'start' and 'end'?

```
<a href="href" title="title">not this</a>start<a href="href" title="title">foo</a>, <a href="href2" title="title2">bar</a>end<a href="href" title="title">not this</a>
```

The following regex give only the last iteration of a.

```
/start((?:<a href="(?<href>.*?)" title="(?<title>.*?)">.*?<\/a>(?:, )?)+)end/g
```

How to have all the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need. 
https://regex101.com/r/isYIeR/1

```
/(?:start)*(?:<a href=(?<href>.*?)\s+title=(?<title>.*?)>.*?<\/a>)+(?:,|end)
```

**UPDATE**

This does not meet the requirement. 
[The Returned Value for a Given Group is the Last One Captured](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

I do not think this can be done in one regex match. Here is a javascript solution with 2 regex matches to get a list of {href, title}

```
var sample='start<a href="href" title="title">foo</a>, <a href="href2" title="title2">bar</a>,<a href="href3" title="title3">bar</a>endstart<img> something end\n' +
    'begin<a href="href" title="title">foo</a>, <a href="href2" title="title2">bar</a>,<a href="href2" title="title2">bar</a>end\n'+
'start<a href="href_1" title="title_1">foo again</a>, <a href="href_2" title="title_2">bar again</a>,<a href="href_3" title="title_3">bar2 again</a>end';
var reg = /start((?:\s*<a href=.*?\s+title=.*?>.*?<\/a>,?)+)end/gi;
var regex2 = /href=(?<href>.*?)\s+title=(?<title>.*?)>/gi;
var step1, step2 ;
var hrefList = [];
while( (step1 = reg.exec(sample)) !== null) {
    while((step2 = regex2.exec(step1[1])) !== null) {
        hrefList.push({href:step2.groups["href"], title:step2.groups["title"]});
    }
}
console.log(hrefList);
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts from that link in your answer? If the link breaks, then your answer loses its value.

Comment: Thanks you. Can you explain please why removing the * just after 'start' will change everything that will be captured?

Answer (score 0):

If the format is constant - ie only href and title for each tag, you can use this regex to find a string which is not `"`", and has `"` and a space or `<` after it using lookahead ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SalITk/1)):

```js
const str = 'start<a href="href" title="title">foo</a>, <a href="href2" title="title2">bar</a>end';

const result = str.match(/[^"]+(?="[\s>])/gi);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
<.*?>
```

removes all html tags
so for example

```
<h1>1. This is a title </h1><ul><a href='www.google.com'>2. Click here </a></ul>
```

After using regex you will get:
1. This is a title 2. Click here

Not sure if this answers your question though.